# Can i use the same node class to create a binary tree and a linked list?

Tags: java

For example, i have this node class:

```
public class node{
int data
node left; /*For binary Tree*/
node right; /*For binary Tree*/
node next; /*For the linked list*/
public node(int d){
this.data=d;
this.left=null;
this.right=null;
this.next=null;
}
```

I want to create all nodes for the binary tree, then using an inorder traversal sequence and finally pass the information to a linkedlist. I have the method to create all nodes for the binary tree working. But i have something like this in the inorder method:

```
 Linkedlist list=new Linkedlist();
 public void InOrder(Node r){
  if(r!=null){
    InOrder(r.left);
    list.Addnode(r.data);  /*
    System.out.println(r.data);
    InOrder(r.right);
   }
  }
```

I am passing the data to the linkedlist by the inorder method. Is this correct? It is possible to pass binary tree data to a linked list with the same node class?
P.D: Sorry for my english.

Comment: I believe it's possible.  Why don't you try it, and see if you run into any problems?

Comment: Please post compilable code. Try to follow Java naming conventions. Best use [mcve] . Technically you can get it to work but a. the structure and invocation are odd. b. Us that what  you want ? a linked list of the ***data***   ? or a linked list of the ***nodes*** ? Also why store a linked list on every node ?

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can get it to work :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Node{

    int data;
    Node left; /*For binary Tree*/
    Node right; /*For binary Tree*/
    Node next; /*For the linked list*/
    static LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();

    public Node(int d){

        data=d;
        left=null;
        right=null;
        next=null;
    }

    public void InOrder(Node r){

        if(r!=null){
            InOrder(r.left);
            list.add(r.data);
            InOrder(r.right);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node[] nodes = new Node[10];

        for(int i=0; i < nodes.length ; i++) {

            nodes[i] = new Node(i*10);
            if(i>0) {
                nodes[i].left = nodes[i-1];
            }
        }

        //sort and add data to linked list
        nodes[nodes.length-1].InOrder(nodes[nodes.length-1]);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
    }
}
```

As you see, the structure and invocation are odd.
To created a linked list of Nodes you can do something like:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Tree{

    LinkedList<Node> list=new LinkedList<>();

    Tree(int numberOfNodes){

        if(numberOfNodes >0) {
            makeNodes(numberOfNodes);
        }

    }

    private void makeNodes(int numberOfNodes) {

        Node[] nodes = new Node[numberOfNodes];

        for(int i=0; i < nodes.length ; i++) {

            Node newNode = new Node(i*10);
            nodes[i] = newNode;

            if(i>0) {
                newNode.left = nodes[i-1];
                nodes[i-1].right = newNode;
            }

            list.add(newNode);
        }
    }

    public void printNodesData(){

        list.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.data));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Tree tree = new Tree(10);
         tree.printNodesData();
    }
}

class Node{
    int data;
    Node left; /*For binary Tree*/
    Node right; /*For binary Tree*/
    Node next; /*For the linked list*/

    public Node(int d){

        data=d;
        left=null;
        right=null;
        next=null;
    }
}
```